# json.load() from file to dict returning error

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to fill a dictionary named `users` from a file using the `json` module:

Here's my code:

```
import json


def load_user_db_file(users: dict):
    with open("user_db_file.txt", 'r') as file:
    users = json.load(file)
```

The error I get is:

```
File "C:/Users/Mendel/PycharmProjects/The-Team/menu.py", line 33, in load_dbs
    load_user_db_file()
TypeError: load_user_db_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'users'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: what is your content of user_db_file.txt file ?

Comment: The error is in the function you have defined:
`load_user_db_file(users: dict)`, it expects that you pass a dict in the function but you are passing it directly as shown in error.
Line 33: menu.py `load_user_db_file()`. Either pass a dict or remove it from def.